# android: how to set custom font for entire application

Tags: android, custom-font

I have developed a very huge application and now i have a requirement of having custom font for all controls in the application. so I want to know the better way to change the font in one shot. The application has more than a hundred XML layout. and i cant change all controls to a custom component with custom font. Please provide a solution to Change the font without altering all the controls in XML.

Comment: I am sure for your particular case but Styles may be may be help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do something like this

```
pacage com.prac;
class MyFontedTextView extends TextView {
    public FontedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
         init();
    }

    private void init() {
     String otfName = "MyCustomOtfFileWhichIPutInAssetsFolder.otf";
     Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), otfName);
     this.setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

Now replace this all over in xml file from your TextViews

```
<com.prac.MyFontedTextView ....        instead of <TextView
```

This change you have to do all over for it to apply

also for the case of button text . Button is also subclass of TextView
So the same can work for button's too

Hope this help or can lead you to the solution you are looking

Comment: this way can benefit you from next time for the case if you wish to change the font. you just have to do it on one place

Comment: I know this technique but thing is I have 100's of XML pages with 1000's of controls in it. should i change all those controls or any alternative is there

Comment: This will go a long way:
`find . -name "*xml" | xargs sed -i 's/<TextView/<com.prac.MyFontedTextView'`

Comment: If you have multiple text views like in a list you should really set access your resources only once. If you can use a single static Typeface variable and then reference that it greatly improves performance. Setting the type face in each view each time from resources is super slow.